# Change a column name on select

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a temporary table.

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
ABC     B01        10       5
ABC     B01        77       5
ABC     B03        30       7
ABC     B05        50      11
ABC     B05        88      11
DEF     B05        50      50
DEF     B05        88      50
DEF     B06        66      50
A01     B02        20       0 
A01     B04        40       0
A02     B02        99       0
```

and this helper table:

```
ID1     ID2
ABC     A01
DEF     A02
```

What I'd like to do. If there are values in col_1 in temporary table that matches ID2 in helper table, the values are changed to ID1 in helper table. How to do this on a `select` ?

So, when I do a select (`SELECT * FROM temporary`). This is the result:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
ABC     B01        10       5
ABC     B01        77       5
ABC     B03        30       7
ABC     B05        50      11
ABC     B05        88      11
DEF     B05        50      50
DEF     B05        88      50
DEF     B06        66      50
ABC     B02        20       0 
ABC     B04        40       0
DEF     B02        99       0
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks for your help

**nb:**

There are a lot of values in helper table. Not just two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join with case

```
select   case
                when h.id2 = tt.col_1 then h.id1
                else tt.col_1
            end as col_1,
            col_2,col_3,col_4
from    temporary_table tt
left join helper h on tt.col_1 = h.id2
```

Comment: there are not only two values in helper table. With the real data there are around 500 values.

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon. I've implemented it to my real data and it works like a charm :D